# How to stop concurrent futures reimporting libraries

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I am learning how to use multiprocessing and tried to use it in a project that also uses pygame. I noticed that, when using concurrent.futures to run multiple tasks, the pygame library keeps getting reinitialized. I boiled the problem down to this code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import pygame

def do_something(seconds):
    print('zzz', seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return 'Wake up'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [executor.submit(do_something, 1) for _ in range(3)]

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print(f.result())

    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} seconds.")
```

With output:

```
python multiprocessing_test.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
zzz 1
zzz 1
zzz 1
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.8.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Wake up
Wake up
Wake up
Finished in 1.54 seconds.
```

Even though I only have 3 processes, the pygame initialization method is called 12 additional times. The function that is being called does not need pygame at all. Does this have something to do with pygame specifically? And is there a way to prevent this?

EDIT: Originally I ran the above code using python 3.8. When using python  3.9, the output changes:

```
python multiprocessing_test.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.16)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.16)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.16)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.16)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
zzz 1
zzz 1
zzz 1
Wake up
Wake up
Wake up
Finished in 1.18 seconds.
```

It now seems to import pygame only 3 additional times.

I ran this code in a standalone folder, using a newly made conda environment with pygame as the only additional library installed.

Comment: No repro - just ran it in the open Python terminal and as a standalone file, and didn't see multiple imports.

Comment: I just realized the behaviour changed when using python 3.9. Which version did you use?

Comment: I think I'm on 3.11 or greater.

Comment: Hmm sadly using 3.11 does not change anything for me